# How to create random number generation inside the Corda flow?

Tags: corda

Is there any build in functionalities available to generate random numbers inside, corda app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard Java random number generation libraries inside Corda flows, e.g.:

```
new Random(); int value = rand.nextInt(100);
```

It is only inside `Contract.verify` that access to random number generators is restricted, since this code must be deterministic.